# Get Video size in MB Android

Tags: android, video, size, media-player

I want to get the video size in Mega Bytes from a Url in an android app. I have a Player that plays a video inside an app. I want to display next to my player the current videos size. So an example would me 23mb. If the video is 23 mg than I would have text next to the video that says 23mb. I tried looking through all the android mp.get functions but could not find what Iam looking for. Please help. Maybe I missed a function in Android. Or mayber there is anouther way to accomplush this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the HTTP `content-length` header will provide the size of the file being downloaded.

Take a look at [`URLConnection.getHeaderField(String key)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29) or [`HttpMessage.getFirstHeader(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#getFirstHeader%28java.lang.String%29) depending on your server access code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this will work in case the http server is giving the file size

URL myUrl = new URL("http://your_url.com/file.mp3");
URLConnection urlConnection = myUrl.openConnection(); 
urlConnection.connect();
int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
    file_size = file_size /1024;

Or second Version try this.

URL myUrl = new URL("http://your_url.com/file.mp3");
myConnection = myUrl.openConnection();
List headersize = myConnection.getHeaderFields().get("content-Lenght");
```